# How to save html and text in the database?

Tags: wpdb, wp-editor, sanitization

I have two fields. The first is for plain text (but with special characters) and the second for html content (wp_editor is used). Both are later needed for [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

```
<textarea style="width:100%;height:200px;" name="doi-altbody"><?php echo $epn_doi_altbody; ?></textarea>

wp_editor( $epn_doi_body, 'doi-body', array( 'editor_height' => '300px' ) );
```

1) How do i correctly secure them after submitting the form and then save them in the database into a custom table that already exist? (esc_attr, sanitize_text_field ...)

2) And when i want to output the content from the database in the exact and original typed version: How do i make this? (wpautop ...)

I have tried a few things in the last days. But it never worked as i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<textarea style="width:100%;height:200px;" name="doi-altbody"><?php echo $epn_doi_altbody; ?></textarea>

wp_editor( $epn_doi_body, 'doi-body', array( 'editor_height' => '300px' ) );
```

To get the same result that was saved to the database the output has to be modified.

For the textarea:

```
wp_specialchars_decode( $epn_doi_altbody, $quote_style = ENT_QUOTES )
```

For the wp_editor:

```
wpautop( $epn_doi_body );
```

Comment: Can you provide additional code? I'm not doing something right. In my form, I have the wp_editor where an admin can enter the text. They might link to a document in the media or perhaps an another resource. When the content is saved, everything has `<img class=\"size-full wp-image-174 alignleft\" src=\"http://localhost:8888/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/user4.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\" /> Some Text goes <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">here</a>.` so when I output it, the image doesn't show and the URL shows up as `http://localhost:8888/http://www.google.com`. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just use the [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) insert and update API, no escaping or sanitizing needed as per the doc, just the raw data.

> **Data**: (array) Data to replace (in column => value pairs). Both $data columns
>   and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped).

Something like:

```
    $wpdb->insert(
      $wpdb->prefix . "myTable",
      array(
        "doiBody" => $_POST['doi-body']
      ),
      array( "%s" )
    );
```

2. No wpautop use is needed if you are outputting into the wp_editor textarea, just an `esc_attr( $output )` would be sufficient I believe.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: The output goes directly to phpmailer as i wrote in my question. And if i do it this way quotes are going to be displayed as "&quot;" in the email from the textarea-version. And in the wp_editor version all the text has no line breaks and is in one line. The last problem is fixed when i use wpautop when giving the content to phpmailer.

Comment: I got it. I had to use on the textfield-version: wp_specialchars_decode( $text, $quote_style = ENT_QUOTES )

Comment: You should sanitize the input at the very least. Could someone do a SQL injection attack here or is that only in other direct DB methods?

Comment: @jgraup The post data is stored into a variable and goes than directly into the database. Also the form is only available in the admin area from the plugin (not a public form). And of course: No direct access to the files is possible.